# Spring Boot Elasticsearch Connection Using SSL

Tags: spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch, ssl, configuration

I want to make a connection btw my client and docker elastic container. While setting up docker container it gave me a http_ca.crt but I can't use it on application.yml. Do I need a config class for this? Can't I handle it using only application.yml file?

spring.elasticsearch.properties.ssl properties don't exist anymore. (CHATGPT support)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.